# When I click Manage Categories, Magento crashes hard

Tags: category, admin, mysql

So when I use the "Manage Categories" under the catalog menu I get the following (editied errors local.xml to show the errors):

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.admin_menutop' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `admin_menutop` AS `main_table` WHERE (`category_id` = '')

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Helper/Data.php(50): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Helper/Data.php(17): Cmsmart_Megamenu_Helper_Data->_categotyFilter()
#10 /var/www/html/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cmsmart/megamenu/menutop.phtml(59): Cmsmart_Megamenu_Helper_Data->getCategoryArr()
#11 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/m...')
#12 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#13 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Cmsmart/Megamenu/Block/Catalog/Category/Tabs.php(165): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Cmsmart_Megamenu_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#18 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#19 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Edit/Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#20 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#21 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#22 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#23 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#24 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#25 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#26 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#27 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#28 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#29 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#30 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#31 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#32 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#33 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#34 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#35 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /var/www/html/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#39 {main}
```

Im guessing the problem lies in the first line and the SQL error.
I cant seem to find any other admin panels that cause the same error.
Info is:

Magento ver. 1.9.2.2 CE hosted on digital ocean

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MegaMenu, was this just installed? Sounds like it failed to add a table.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a sql setup version mismatch with the core_resource table .

Possibility is that you installed this extension before and there is already a entry in the core_resource table , Later the tables has been deleted but still the entry already existed in core_resource.

So next time same extension installation it will skip the install file which is the base table code file and then the code use the base table which is not installed .

So it may show an error .

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall extension you have installed and then check again. Or you can add table manually in the database by checking from installer file that is in SQL folder of your extension.